# ERROR: recursive query "t" column 3 has type character varying(255) in non-recursive term but type character varying overall

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have this table.

```
CREATE TABLE directory (
  id           INT NOT NULL,
  parent_id    INT,
  label        character varying(255),
  
  CONSTRAINT pk_directory PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_directory FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES t_directory (id)
);
```

I'm trying to build a hierarchy so I have done this in jOOQ.

```
CommonTableExpression<?> cte = name("t").fields(
  "id",
  "name",
  "path"
).as(
  select(
    DIRECTORY.ID,
    DIRECTORY.LABEL,
    DIRECTORY.LABEL)
  .from(DIRECTORY)
  .where(DIRECTORY.PARENT_ID.isNull())
  .unionAll(
  select(
    DIRECTORY.ID,
    DIRECTORY.LABEL,
    field(name("t", "path"), VARCHAR)
      .concat("\\")
      .concat(DIRECTORY.LABEL))
  .from(table(name("t")))
  .join(DIRECTORY)
  .on(field(name("t", "id"), INTEGER)
    .eq(DIRECTORY.PARENT_ID)))
);

System.out.println(
    create().withRecursive(cte)
            .selectFrom(cte)
            .fetch()
);
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR: recursive query "t" column 3 has type character varying(255) in
> non-recursive term but type character varying overall

If I change the cast from VARCHAR to TEXT it works but **PostgresDataType.TEXT** is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

Anyone knows the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get same error if you convert it to sql and run in postgresql. What you need is cast:

```
      WITH RECURSIVE t(id, name, path) as (
      
      select
      ID,
      LABEL,
      LABEL
     from DIRECTORY 
      where PARENT_ID is null
    union all 
      select d.ID,
      d.LABEL,
      cast(t.path || '\\' || d.label as varchar(255)) 
  -- ^^^^^^^ you need jOOQ equivalent of cast
             from t
                join directory d on (t.id = d.parent_id)

  ) select * from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue caused by a direct application of [the `WITH RECURSIVE` example from the jOOQ manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/with-recursive-clause/). An [example improvement is on the way](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12067).

In PostgreSQL, you'll have to cast both subqueries of the recursive `UNION ALL` query like this:

```java
DIRECTORY.LABEL.cast(VARCHAR(255))
// ...
field(name("t", "path"), VARCHAR)
      .concat("\\")
      .concat(DIRECTORY.LABEL).cast(VARCHAR(255))
```

Where the above uses the usual static imports:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.*;
```

Alternatively, you could use `TEXT` as a column type in your table declaration:

```sql
CREATE TABLE directory (
  id           INT NOT NULL,
  parent_id    INT,
  label        TEXT, -- Use TEXT instead
  
  CONSTRAINT pk_directory PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_directory FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES directory (id)
);
```

Apparently, PostgreSQL doesn't require casts in that case.

> If I change the cast from VARCHAR to TEXT it works but PostgresDataType.TEXT is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

The standard SQL type that corresponds to `TEXT` in jOOQ is `SQLDataType.CLOB`.